# Ignore trailing slash in django url regex

Tags: regex, django

I want to catch from all urls like

`example.com/<page_path>` or `example.com/<page_path>/`

the `<page_path>` part. The variable could be empty (redirect to `example.com/start`) or a path to the desired page (most of the time a simple string, but can also have slashes in it)

This is my current `urls.py` which seems to work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/$', RedirectView.as_view(url="start"), name='index'),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url="start"), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>.+)/$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='page'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>.+)$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='page'),
]
```

But now I tried to simplify the expression and came up with this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/?$', RedirectView.as_view(url="start"), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>.+)/?$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='page'),
]
```

I want to capture everything except if there is a trailing slash.

Strange is, this works for

- `example.com`
- `example.com/`
- `example.com/start`

but not for

- `example.com/start/`

Can someone point my error out?

Comment: change your urls to :
 url(r'^(?P<page>[-\w]+)/?$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='page'),

Comment: i have only changed the regx. Instead of '.+' use '[-\w]+', this should work.

Comment: what @anush said, your current regex is too greedy and is grabbing the slash on the end too as part of `page`, so there is nothing left for the `/?` part to work on

Comment: You don't need `r'^/?$`, `r'^$'` will work fine whether you type `example.com` or `example.com/`.

Comment: Yes you were all right. It works now. But @Alasdair , could you explain why `r'^$'` also works. Is this some kind of special case?

Comment: If you look at the request for `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/` in your logs, you'll see `"GET / HTTP/1.1"`, whether or not you include the slash. Django strips the leading slash from the request before resolving the url. So if you have `r'^/$'`, it will actually match `//`, which isn't what you want. You don't need a leading slash in `r'^$'` in the same way as you don't put a leading slash in `r'^(?P<page>.+)'`. Django 1.9 will [check your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#urls) for this mistake, and a couple of others.

Comment: got it now. Thanks for the great explanation :) @Alasdair

Answer (score 3):

There is a Django setting called `APPEND_SLASH` with default value `True`:

> When set to `True`, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.
>
> The `APPEND_SLASH` setting is only used if CommonMiddleware is installed.

Source: [Django documentation: Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: Interesting, but my problem is more the other way around. I want urls that end with a slash and don't match any pattern to be redirected to the same URL without the slash.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your comments I could fix it with this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url="start"), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>.+?)/?$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='page'),
]
```

The `+` quantifier was too greedy, so I replaced it with the non-greedy version `+?`.